# Activities during the winter in Dubrovnik

Tags: winter, dubrovnik

I am planning my honeymoon in mid-February. We thought that Dubrovnik would be a good idea because it's a pretty place, it should not be overly crowded around the time, the carnival would be fun, and if we get bored of the beach then there would be many day trips.
I come from tropical Singapore and I would prefer a cooler destination than a warm one. And I am not interested in a place which has nothing to offer but the sea - we do have plenty of that around.

But I have now received some warnings on the winter experience being not so good because of the climate and, more importantly, a limited set of things to do.
I would like to know which of the following might be unavailable in mid-Feb.
1) Sea kayaking and boat trips to Elaphite and Mljet
2) Day trips to places like Plitviče
3) City tours (inc Game of Thrones tours)
4) Concerts
5) What fraction of restaurants would be closed?

Thanks for your advice!

-Ankur

Comment: I was there in late November on the last week the restaurants were open. It became a ghost town after. I doubt many, if any, tourist activities will be open or offered regularly. You would have better luck in April or late March I think, but I'm pretty sure February is solidly in the "closed" season.